LocalContentAlpha not found in compositionLocalProvider
I am learning the android compose and in the course they have use CompositionLocalProvider but in latest version of android its giving this error. LocalContentAlpha its not found its showing in red and no import to that.
How can I solve this? Is this deprecated?
   CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text(
                    text = meal.description,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    maxLines = if (isExpanded) 10 else 4
                )
            }

